# Converting from string to date

Tags: vba, date, excel, text-files

**Short story:**

My question is two fold:

1. How do I copy over this text `05-Jun-2014` from a text file so that the text `05-Jun-2014` does not get displayed as `#NAME?` or get cut off at `5`? (I need the whole thing copied over.)
2. How do I take that text and make it a date?

**Long story**

In this text file I have dates in this format `day-month-year`, e.g `05-Jun-2014`. 
As you see, the "e" in June is cut off. If I type in `05-Jun-2014` in excel, it recognizes it. I use `CDate` to convert the string to a date.

My problem is multi-fold. Essentially I want excel vba to recognize `05-Jun-2014` as a date.

If I try to copy the phrase `05-Jun-2014` from my text document. I will only get `5` to copy over. I copy the string to a jagged array `jaggArray` and from there I call it.

Below you can see my code for how I copy text:

```
Private Function createGCStruct(ByRef tempString() As String, ByVal aNum As Integer, ByVal oNum As Integer, _
ByRef oList() As String, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal gcSoiDate As Date, ByVal gcFName As String, _
ByVal typeName As String) As gcBStruct

'...code...

' JaggedArray:
Dim jaggArray() As Variant

'...code...

'2) Capture structure information from textfile array

    'A) remove unnecessary spaces from existing Array and Place into jaggedArray
    jaggArray = splitStringArrayElements(tempString)

'...code...

End Function
```

splitStringArrayElements Function():

```
Private Function splitStringArrayElements(tempString() As String) As Variant()
' 1) Variables:
    Dim j As Long
    Dim trimmedString As String
    Dim jaggArray() As Variant
    ReDim jaggArray(LBound(tempString()) To UBound(tempString()))
    Dim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder() As String
    ReDim emptyStringArrayPlaceholder(0 To 0)
' 2) Remove unwanted spaces from tempString() and create a JaggedArray
    For j = LBound(tempString()) To UBound(tempString())
        ' Remove spaces inbetween
        trimmedString = Trim(tempString(j))
        ' If empty line, array is empty
        If trimmedString = "" Then
            jaggArray(j) = emptyStringArrayPlaceholder
        ' Else add array without spaces
        Else
            jaggArray(j) = SplitAdv(trimmedString, " ")
        End If
    Next j

    splitStringArrayElements = jaggArray
End Function
```

splitAdv() Function:

```
Public Function SplitAdv(ByVal InputText As String, Optional ByVal Delimiter As String) As Variant

' This function splits the sentence in InputText into
' words and returns a string array of the words. Each
' element of the array contains one word.

    ' This constant contains punctuation and characters
    ' that should be filtered from the input string.
    Const CHARS = """-" 'Potential options are: "!?,.;:""'()[]{}"
    Dim strReplacedText As String
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    ' Replace tab characters with space characters.
    strReplacedText = Trim(Replace(InputText, _
         vbTab, " "))

    ' Filter all specified characters from the string.
    For intIndex = 1 To Len(CHARS)
        strReplacedText = Trim(Replace(strReplacedText, _
            Mid(CHARS, intIndex, 1), " "))
    Next intIndex

    ' Loop until all consecutive space characters are
    ' replaced by a single space character.
    Do While InStr(strReplacedText, "  ")
        strReplacedText = Replace(strReplacedText, _
            "  ", " ")
    Loop

    ' Split the sentence into an array of words and return
    ' the array. If a delimiter is specified, use it.
    'MsgBox "String:" & strReplacedText
    If Len(Delimiter) = 0 Then
        SplitAdv = VBA.Split(strReplacedText)
    Else
        SplitAdv = VBA.Split(strReplacedText, Delimiter)
    End If
End Function
```

If I remove the `-` when I copy, the three parts become: `5-Jan-00  #NAME?  14:42:58`

Here is where I copy over the date to a structure (assuming i removed the "-"). My goal was to copy over the parts of the date "`05`", "`Jun`", and "`2014`", and then recombine them in this format: `05 Jun,2014`, and then try to convert that to a date:

```
Dim rDStart As Integer      ' row of first gcDate
Dim cDStart As Integer      ' col of first gcDate
Dim tempD1 As Date
Dim tempD2 As Date
rDStart = 6                                            ' the row of the first gcDate
cDStart = 2                                            ' the column of the first gcDate
'Collect gcDate
'***I get my errors below***
tempD1 = CDate(jaggArray(rDStart - 1)(cDStart - 1) & " " & jaggArray(rDStart - 1)(cDStart) & ", " & jaggArray(rDStart - 1)(cDStart + 1))
tempD2 = CDate(jaggArray(rDStart - 1)(cDStart + 2))
createGCStruct.gcDate = tempD1 + tempD2
```

Comment: CDate can't return a #NAME error. I think you left out the important part of how you populate the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `CDate` without splitting the string at all. `CDate` will recognise many date formats, and as long as they are not ambiguous (which `"05-Jun-2014"` isn't), the conversion should work just fine. This works for me:

```
Dim d As Date
d = CDate("05-Jun-2014")
With Range("A1")
    .Value = d
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: Okay, how would I make sure I capture "05-Jun-2014" from a text document without have any part of it changed. Whenever I try to capture it, something goes wrong: either the date is cut off or some #Name? is copied instead.

Comment: Well, clean up your question, remove most of it, keeping only the essential bits. One of these essential bits would be an example of what the text file looks like. Then we can help.

Answer (score 2):

The way to create a "#NAME?" message with VBA is to do the following:

```
Range("A1") = "=05-Jun-2014"
```

Note that the "=" operator causes Excel to treat the following as an expression which in this case would be 5 minus Jun minus 2014.  Because you have no function defined with the NAME 'Jun' you get the "#NAME?" message.

The following does not produce an error and Excel also correctly recognises the value as a date.

```
Range("A1") = "05-Jun-2014"
```

I suggest that you review where you are placing the value into the sheet which I believe is the likely source of the bug.